# Pygame not detecting axes for g29 wheel

Tags: python, pygame, joystick

I have a logitech g29 steering wheel and when I run my code the name is correct however no axes show up. I would like to have my steering axes show up so I can log them and eventually maybe even move the wheel with code.

I have already tried copying code but even that didn't work so I am starting to think something is up with my wheel even though a program called wheel tester detects my wheel and its axes correctly.

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.joystick.init()


joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)

joystick.init()

joy_name = joystick.get_name()
print(joy_name)#<----detected and correct name

print(joystick.get_numaxes())#<---- this returns zero
```

output:
name: Logitech G29 Driving Force Racing Wheel USB |
number of axes: 0

but I believe this wheel has 4 axes

Comment: PyGame is built on [C/C++ library SDL (Simple DirectMedia Layer)](https://www.libsdl.org/). Maybe problem is SDL or maybe you should search in Google `SDL Logitech G29`

Comment: did you check `get_numhats()` and `get_numbuttons()` - maybe it uses buttons or hats instead of standard axes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I met the same problem. Installing [pygame_sdl2](https://github.com/renpy/pygame_sdl2) saved me. It is a reimplementation of the Pygame API using SDL2 instead of SDL. 
After following the instructions to build pygame_sdl2, you can just run your code by
`import pygame_sdl2 as pygame`

Comment: Thank you that worked! Sorry for the late reply but I put the project to the side for a while